# AS3 Drag and Drop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, z-index

I want to make a pairing-ups by drag and drop. There are three items are supposed to move on corresponding other three items on the stage. However I can predict that adding children dynamically change the all indexes (z/depth/whatever). So when 'accidentally' someone hovers over a matched pair, mouse will be over item but dragged one stands behind. At that time 'dropping' will possibly ruin the programme.

Is there any way to avoid that situation? Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set dragging object above all:

```
Sprite(draggingObject.parent).setChildIndex(draggingObject, Sprite(draggingObject.parent).numChildren - 1);
```

also you need to listen MOUSE_UP event at stage value.

Worked example:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
var dragged:Sprite;
addChild(container);
var card:Sprite;
for (var j:uint = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    card = new Sprite();
    container.addChild(card);
    card.buttonMode = true;
    card.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    card.graphics.drawRect(0,0,30,30);
    card.x = j*40;
    card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stardDragListener);
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragEvent);
function stardDragListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
    dragged = Sprite(e.currentTarget);
    Sprite(dragged.parent).setChildIndex(dragged, Sprite(dragged.parent).numChildren - 1)
    dragged.startDrag();
}
function stopDragEvent(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (dragged) dragged.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: It will highly possible throw 'The Supplied Index is Out of Bounds' since the dragging object might be the first in the index.

Comment: do you set numChildren - 1 or numChildren?

Comment: Is there a way we can alter the index continuously? Like if other object added to stage change index of former...

@fresh-flash it was minus 1

Comment: use container for all dragged childrens to depths discipline:) I add worked code above

Comment: Thank you. I have taken it and I'll give it a try. And one last thing. How can I give coordinates to container and/or children of it ('dragged')? I have xs and ys for dragged items but none for container.

Comment: do you need global coordinates? There is localToGlobal method: container.localToGlobal(new Point(dragged.x, dragged.y));

Comment: I am not sure the method helps but on second glance it is probably nothing related to x and y, position or coordinate.

Comment: localToGlobal return global point. Point has x and y properties.